# Building Non-Directed Graphs using Graphsharp framework

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworks, graph-theory, graph-sharp

Is it possible to generate non-directed graph using the Graphsharp framework in WPF?

I could only manage to generate directed graph, I tried searching it on my own, but didn't figure it out if there is an appropriate class built-in to create such non-directed graph.

Due to lack of the documentation about this framework I ask for your help. Maybe someone has a similar problem.

Comment: Probably not want you want to hear, but as far as I can see, that package was abandoned some time ago. You might be better searching for something that is actively being developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to convert your graph:

See **GraphLayout.cs** specifically where

- TGraph : class, **IBidirectionalGraph**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// THE layout control. Support layout, edge routing and overlap removal algorithms, with multiple layout states.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TVertex">Type of the vertices.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TEdge">Type of the edges.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TGraph">Type of the graph.</typeparam>
public partial class GraphLayout<TVertex, TEdge, TGraph>
    where TVertex : class
    where TEdge : IEdge<TVertex>
    where TGraph : class, IBidirectionalGraph<TVertex, TEdge>
{
```